# bash_profile not found in my home directory [MacOS Big Sur]

Tags: macos, macos-big-sur

bash_profile not found in my home directory but if I'm run `echo $PATH` there some output `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin`. so where the bash_profiles and how to I edit bash_profile and set other path permanently?

Comment: run command "touch ~/.bash_profile" and you are good. It will create file at /Users/<username>/.bash_profile It is not a problem that is empty file

Comment: I tried this and set new path in that file, but when I try `echo $PATH` the output is still old path not my new path

Comment: $PATH has nothing to do with .bash_profile. $PATH is a variable used by system to look for executables. Profile is not executable (cannot run because it is a text file)

Answer (score 0):

Since macOS **Catalina** (10.15) or newer, the default shell on macOS is no more **bash** but **zsh**. That's why bash files like bash_history, bash_sessions etc... are not set in your home directory. You can check what shell is define in your Terminal with this command ? `echo $SHELL`

You can use this command to change your shell `chsh -s /bin/bash` or in Terminal app go to "Preferences" to modify the default shell configuration.

Create a **.profile** in your home directory and add the command `export BASH_SILENCE_DEPRECATION_WARNING=1` to deactivate warnings.

Close your Terminal's window and open a new one to validate the change.

Comment: `echo $SHELL` give output `/bin/bash`, and run `chsh -s /bin/bash` give output `chsh: no changes made`.  `a.profile` can I create manually from finder? and I set new path in `a.profile`?

Comment: Yes you can do it manually in your home dir in Terminal `touch .profile` or `echo export BASH_SILENCE_DEPRECATION_WARNING=1 > .profile`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `~/.zprofile` for zsh (for Catalina and Big Sur)